# Whatsapp Share Android 11 Scoped Storage

Tags: android, whatsapp, mediastore, saf

I used this code without a problem up to Android 10. But now under Android 11 it doesn't work anymore. I think Whatsapp can't read the mp3 in the app directory created from the raw resource.

My skills are not that good, that I understand SAF or MediaStore. I think that's the problem and general, that WhatsApp don't have permission for my app directory. So I just wan't to download it to Download/ or similiar path which would be shared storage. But how?

Target SDK is 30

My code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>

<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b"/>
</queries>
```

```
private void shareButton(int shareplayint) {
            try {
                String mediaPath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(shareplayint);
                Intent shareMedia = new Intent();
                shareMedia.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // Content of mediaPath = /storage/emulated/0/ANdroid/data/stutz.com.swissbuttons/files/swissbuttons.mp3
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mediaPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                shareMedia.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareMedia.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(mediaPath));
                shareMedia.setType("audio/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareMedia, "senden"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp isch nit installiert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    private String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId) {

        String pathSDCard = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/swissbuttons.mp3";

        try {
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pathSDCard;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The file will be effectivly saved under android 11. But Whatsapp can't handle that.

Comment: `Uri.parse(mediaPath))` Value of mediaPath?

Comment: `mediaPath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(shareplayint)` What are you copying? And what is the value of shareplayint?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with whatsapp. You should explain that first.

Comment: `So I just wan't to download it to Download/ or similiar path | What is it that you want to download? Why didnt you start with telling us that?