# If I use Media Store APIs, where will the files be stored?

Tags: android, storage, whatsapp, mediastore

I have some doubts regarding the storage in the android!

If I use Media Store APIs, where will the files be stored?

I am making a messenger like WhatsApp and am stuck in the storage part? Please help me!

I am open to suggestions for making an efficient messenger app! Please recommend any resources!

Comment: They will be stored in public directories of your device and or subdirectories of them. Just like you gave values to storage variables.

Comment: @blackapps I tried to explain all the confusion I had in there. please help!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341641/whatsapp-share-android-11-scoped-storage